# How to fix Discord package error?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, configuration

When I downloaded discord-0.0.14.deb, I remove 0.0.13 and install 0.0.14, and this message

```
unable to install discord: error while installing package: installed gconf2-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

shows up. So, I thought something must wrong and tried to uninstall it but got this message after uninstalling the process

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

shows up.

Then, I search for the problem and found this page [How to Fix sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) in Ubuntu](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1)

then, I typed this command :

```
sudo dpkg ––configure –a
```

And I got this error

```
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

How do I fix it? sorry for the grammar.

Comment: Also, please post more of the output. The actual error was earlier than the one you posted. The error lines typically begin with `E:`

Comment: The last error is because you probably copied and pasted the command from an improperly formatted website so instead of regular [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) dashes like these `sudo dpkg --configure -a` your command has slightly longer [figure-dashes or en-dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) like these `sudo dpkg ––configure –a`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: I redownloaded discord(deb version), opened it with Software Install(Ubuntu Software), and installed it with the Software Install. The app is actually installed but in software install, it said 
"Unable to install discord:
Error while installing package: install gcon2-common
package post-insatllation script subprocess returned error exit
status 1"